# How to use Windows authentication to connect to Sql express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have a `.env` file that contains the below and I am using tedious connection pool.

```
SQL_SERVER=localhost
SQL_UNAME=US\JENNY
SQL_PSWD=Windows password
SQL_DB=DatabaseName
```

But I am getting login failed error as shown below:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'US\JENNY'

Below is my dbconfig file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
    userName: process.env.SQL_UNAME,
    password: process.env.SQL_PSWD,
    server: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    options: {
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
        encrypt: false,
        database: process.env.SQL_DB,
        rowCollectionOnDone: true,
        useColumnNames: true // for easier JSON formatting
   }
};
```

Comment: lemme try that out!

Comment: still getting errors

Comment: do i have to configure differently for windows authentication? It works when I create a login for SQL server authentication but my windows account has higher access to other databases I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what version of Tedious you're using.  I bring it up because userName and password have been moved into an authentication section, so your current config would get you a deprecation warning.

But if you are using a current version, the authentication section also has an authentication.type setting that you can set to ntlm.  See http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newConnection for details.

The following connection config works for a windows based login for me:

```
module.exports = {
    server: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    options: {
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
        encrypt: false,
        database: process.env.SQL_DB,
        rowCollectionOnDone: true,
        useColumnNames: true
    },
    authentication: {
        type: 'ntlm',
        options: {
            userName: process.env.SQL_UNAME,
            password: process.env.SQL_PSWD,
            domain: process.env.SQL_DOMAIN
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What would I define for the SQL domain?

Comment: Nevermind I changed it and updated to latest version of tedious. It still won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the link though! hopefully I can get it after further reading documentation.

Comment: @Jen - the domain is the active directory domain that your user is in.  In your example, "US" is your domain and "JENNY" is your username.

Comment: can tedious work with windows authentication though?

Comment: Yes it works fine.  Set the authentication type to NTLM, use your windows user name, windows password and windows domain name.